# Slow SQL Server database response time issue

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, garbage-collection

I am running a desktop based application built in C# connected to a Microsoft SQL Server Express database. About 20-30 users are accessing this application while 20-30 more systems are connected with database at the same time and it is working 24 hours daily. OS running is Windows Server 2012 Standard.

Sometimes I am facing serious performance issues in the application, when I am restarting server everything is becoming normal.

I already scanned all computers and there is no virus detected. Looks like no problem in network devices as well.

What could be the problem? Garbage collection?

Thanks

Comment: How are you handling connection to the database in code? If you are not disposing of connections, then there will be issues with the connection not being put back into the connection pool, meaning threads will end up waiting for a connection to become available. You may also have table lock issues, where you may have multiple users attempting updates/inserts which will cause records or tables to be locked to prevent conflicts. This, combined with connections not being disposed, can cause what you have described

Comment: I am Opening Connections only when needed and Closing at the End of CRUD operation. Here is example of it
`try
            {
             }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exp.Message.ToString(), "Exception");
            }
            finally
            {
                if (sqlConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                sqlConnection.Close();
            }
            }`

Comment: can you check sql server cpu,memory usage while you are facing perf issues and update question

Comment: @TheGameiswar is there any tool that can help me to collect data of CPU, Memory Usage and make a comparison report based on old Usage ???

Comment: search for `collect cpu performance metrics sql server`

Comment: SQL Server **Express** - being a **free** tool - is strictly limited in terms of CPU and RAM it can use. With 20-30 concurrent users, I'm thinking you're probably overstretching those limits. If you really have 20-30 concurrent users for a serious business application, you should consider buying a full SQL Server license without the Express limitations

Comment: AFAIK SQL Server 2014 developer is free now, maybe you can update your server?

Comment: @gofr1,SQL Server 2014 developer is free for development only not for production.

Comment: @M.Hassan totally agree! Anyway it is better then SQL Server Express for production ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are imitations for the SQL Server Express Edition:

- Number of CPUs supported: Only one CPU at a time (max core =4 for sql express 2016). So, if your server has multiple CPUs, it will use only one CPU at a time.
- Maximum memory used : A maximum of 1 GB memory for data buffer. So, if your server has more GB memeory, SQL Server Express cannot take advantage of it.
- Database size limit: Maximum database size is limited to 4 GB (10GB for sql express 2016)

DISK I/O speed and Memory are one of the main resources for sql performance. As data are in cache for long time, server read from memory not from disk.

One of the measures that can help of finding server performance bottleneck  is measuring the  Page Life Expectancy (PLE). It should be >300 for server with 4GB memory (but really sql express use limited 1GB).

PLE  is the number of seconds the average page of data has been in the buffer pool.  Keeping the data in memory gives SQL Server quicker access to it instead of making the long, slow trip to disk. This  measure can open your eyes and lead you towards issues that can be resolved.
you can get by executing:

```
SELECT  object_name,
    counter_name,
    cntr_value AS [value]
FROM    sys.dm_os_performance_counters
WHERE   LTRIM(RTRIM(object_name)) = 'SQLServer:Buffer Manager'
    AND LTRIM(RTRIM(counter_name)) = 'Page life expectancy' ;
```

In sql express you loose the key resources (memory limitation 1GB) that help in enhancing PLE counter.

Your system is  20-30 users plus  20-30 more systems are connected with database at the same time and it is working 24 hours daily.

It's better to upgrade to SQL Standard Edition 2016 with no limitation of Memory (up to 128GB) and CPU/Cores (up to 24 core).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the Windows Performance Counters.

My first look would be *SQLServer:Memory Manager: Total Server Memory (KB)* and *SQLServer:Memory Manager: Target Server Memory (KB)*.
Also have a look at *Buffer:Cache Hit Ratio* counter.

If target memory is higher than total memory increase memory. 
If cache hit ratio on average is below 99% also increase memory.